# exteranl native build issues,build command failed, android studio

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, android-studio-3.1.3

i posted one question about a problem that i was having,and it was answer but appear another problems less than before, but it follow being a problems that i really don t understand, because i am new in doing app android with android studio. those were the consoles errors that give me android studios:

first:

```
null 
Build command failed. 
Error while executing process C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app -BC:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++14 -fexceptions -frtti -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc-4.9} 
C:/Users/Raul del Rio/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2 
../../AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake 
 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake">Open File</a> 
 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake">Open File</a> 
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage 
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
Build command failed. 
Error while executing process C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app -BC:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++14 -fexceptions -frtti -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc-4.9} 
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage   
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

here is the other console:

```
Build command failed.


Error while executing process C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app -BC:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++14 -fexceptions -frtti -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc-4.9}


 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
Open File


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!


Build command failed.


Error while executing process C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app -BC:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-15 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++14 -fexceptions -frtti -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Raul del Rio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc-4.9}


 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
Open File


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

this was the change that i did to solve the past problem:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rauldelrio.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments '-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF', '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc-4.9'
            cppFlags "-std=c++14 -fexceptions -frtti"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem too. I think my C compiler / NDK environment was corrupted for some reason. However reinstalling these tools fixed the problem.

Steps to reinstall C / NDK environment:

- Android menu: Tools > SDK Manager
- Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK
- SDK Tools tab
- Uncheck CMake, LLDB, NDK and click OK (to uninstall them)
- Check CMake, LLDB, NDK and click OK (to install them again - takes some time)

After forcing a refresh of the tools, everything compiled correctly again.